# Please tell me the name of this jquery menu

Tags: jquery, menu

could please someone can tell me the name of this type of jquery menu?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/10/97395002.png/

Comment: Hi @Side, just to make sure... do you mean the image rotator? Or the menu at the top?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the image rotator that you mean....

Typically jquery plug-ins are in separate files.

It appears to be jquery rotate http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

The easiest way to find that out yourself is to search the html source code for ".js" to see what JavaScript files are included.

Or the way I approached it was using [Google Chrome's developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html) and see what resources (in this case js files) are downloaded.

I think the rotate buttons are probably custom made and not part of the rotate plugin.